# Is there any way to use attribute for Controller Action to allow specific hostname

Tags: c#, attributes, asp.net-core-webapi

I has a Customer microservice with 2 Controller Actions:

One used by user with permission, no problem with this

One used by system request from Gateway microservice (a microservice I use for doing complicated action that require multiple actions from multiple microservices), this should not require any permission, but it must be called from Gateway microservice

```
[HttpPut("{id}/restore")]
[Authorize(Roles = PermissionConstants.RestoreCustomer)]
public async Task<CustomerResModel> RestoreCustomer(int id)
{
    return (await _customerService.RestoreCustomer(id)).ToResModel();
}

[HttpPut("{id}/restore-by-order")]
[AllowHostNames(_sitemapUrl.BaseGatewayUrl, "localhost:44302")] //any way to do this ?
public async Task<CustomerResModel> RestoreCustomerByRestoreOrder(int id)
{
    return (await _customerService.RestoreCustomer(id)).ToResModel();
}
```

so, is there any way to use something like `[AllowHostNames(_sitemapUrl.BaseGatewayUrl, "localhost:44302")]` to allow only some specific hostnames have the right to call some specific Action Apis

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @PeterCsala [AllowHostNames(_sitemapUrl.BaseGatewayUrl, "localhost:44302")] //any way to do this to filter the source of request ?

Comment: I'm unaware of action level host filtering. You can define [this on the kestrel level](https://andrewlock.net/adding-host-filtering-to-kestrel-in-aspnetcore/).

Comment: @PeterCsala I only need this for some specific actions, not all, so "filtering to Kestrel" is not cool and will make me has to refactor most of my code because that filter will make most apis not working anymore

Comment: I do understand your need but I'm unaware of any built-in solution which works on this level of granularity. If you want you can implement a custom `ActionFilter` and you can decide inside the [`OnActionExecuting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iactionfilter.onactionexecuting?view=aspnetcore-6.0) whether or not the execution should be continued based on the request: `if(!IsAllowed(context.HttpContext.Request..Headers["Referer"])) context.Result = StatusCode(401)`

Comment: The only way to do this is using JWT. Google to find more.